# How can I configure two Postfixes so one forwards emails to another for routing

Tags: postfix

I can easily configure Postfix host A to forward all emails to other Postfix host B like that:

```
relayhost = b.domain.com:25
```

But how can I tell host B to accept ALL traffic from A for full email processing/routing.
There are no mailboxes on B. It's just a smarthost for routing.

Answer (score 2):

The [Postfix documentation](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_relay_restrictions) states:

> By default, the Postfix SMTP server accepts:
>
> - Mail from clients whose IP address matches `$mynetworks`, or:
> - Mail to remote destinations that match `$relay_domains`, except for addresses that contain sender-specified routing (user@elsewhere@domain), or:
> - Mail to local destinations that match `$inet_interfaces` or `$proxy_interfaces`, `$mydestination`, `$virtual_alias_domains`, or `$virtual_mailbox_domains`.

As you cannot possible list each and every domain in `$relay_domains` I suggest you make sure the IP address that server A uses to forward email to server B is listed in B's `$mynetworks`. That way server B should accept and forward all emails from server A.